# make a C program relaunch itself after x seconds

Tags: c, windows

Is it possible to make a program written in C to stop and then relaunch itself after **x** seconds In windows ?? And if yes, how to make it happen ??

Comment: What do you mean by "relaunch"?

Comment: In a simple way "He will kill himself (completely disappear from task manager, but before doing that, he asks the OS to launch it back after some seconds (or minutes)".

Comment: How about `setjmp`, `longjmp`, and blocking instead?

Comment: how to use setjmp and longjmp to relaunch ??!!

Comment: Once a process dies, it cannot, by definition, take any further action.  So no, a program cannot relaunch itself in the way you describe.

Comment: A program could ask the OS or a different program to launch another instance of it at some future time, however.

Comment: I know that it cannot take any actions when it dies, but I thought may be there is some kind of OS functionality that allows that (like starting a program at OS startup). It's just like the program is saying to the OS "I am going to die now, do some spelling to bring me back to life after x seconds".

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's what exactly what I am looking for. How to ask the OS to launch another instance of the program in the future ??

Comment: In Linux I might be inclined to use the `at` command.  Windows in fact has an analog with the same name, but I am uncertain whether it exhibits the necessary properties.  If it does then you should be able to use the `system()` function to run that command and thereby schedule a relaunching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that goal by having your program launch a second program, whose only function is to wait a while and then launch your first program again. In pseudocode, the idea would be:

```
Program A:
  Do whatever the program is supposed to do
  Launch program B
  exit.
Program B:
  Wait predetermined time
  Launch program A
  exit.
```

I hope this answers your question adequately.

Comment: Thanks man, it as a very usefull way, but I am looking for a more native way to do it (like a function, or using a system call).

Comment: For an amusing variation on this approach, read the story of the Robin Hood and Friar Tuck hack in the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/meaning-of-hack.html).

Comment: @Sidahmed You could use `system()` to launch the two programs, each one calling the other. On Windows (and maybe others, I'm not sure) you can use `CreateProcess()` within a program to launch another one. What I like about `CreateProcess()` is 1: You can specify that no console window is to be opened, so your other process can run invisibly, and 2: `CreateProcess()` returns immediately, so you can exit your program while the other one is running.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this kind of thing is with a command-line option 'startDelay=xx'.

If there is no such command, my app just starts up as normal.  If there is, its first action , before attempting to open any files, DB, construct GUI, start threads, start server etc. is to sleep for 'xx' seconds.

If my app needs to restart itself, it copies its own command-line, adds the 'startDelay=xx' to it and launches a new copy of itself, which then immediately sleeps.  The original then has plenty of time to shut down normally before the new copy starts the bulk of its run-up.

No need for any other app or Windows scheduler and/or cron crap:)